# Php Routing array_key_exists vs foreach

Tags: php, foreach, routes, preg-match

I found 2 ways to this and I'm looking for what style here would be less overhead and more efficient. Does anyone know what one is best? This project might have alot of links and get big arrays.

## 1

```
foreach($this->routes as $pattern => $action) {

    if($pattern === $uri) {
        return $action;
    }

    if(preg_match('#^' . $pattern . '$#', $uri, $matched)) {
        return $action;
    }

}
```

## 2

```
if(array_key_exists($uri, $routes)) {
    return $routes[$uri];
}

foreach($this->routes as $pattern => $action) {
    if(preg_match('#^' . $pattern . '$#', $uri, $matched)) {
        return $action;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_key_exists` should be significantly faster than the loop, since it's just a hash lookup rather than a sequential search. The difference probably won't be noticeable, though, because whenever the lookup fails you're going to go into the loop looking for a regexp match.

Comment: i was worrying about when it looks for regex routes it will check array_key_exists and then go into a foreach loop, and with #2 it just goes to the foreach loop and doesn't have to check.

Comment: That's not what #2 does.

Comment: `array_key_exists()` is cheap. Unless the match is one of the first routes, doing the check first will be less expensive.